# Access variable of a class inside other classes Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a class which has variables like this:

```
class MyDragTarget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String assetImage;
  final String name;

  MyDragTarget(this.name, this.assetImage);
}
```

EDIT: Sorry for wrong code below. I knew how to use widget.name to get name of the parent. But how can i get name of other class.
Should i use InheritedWidget? To use InheritedWidget must i learn Provider?

I want to access the name and assetImage of MyDragTarget in another class such as:

```
class Another extends StatefulWidget {
  print(MyDragTarget.name);
}
```

Comment: you can either pass your class object as parameter through all your classes, but this will create so much boilerplate so you either should use [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) or [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-readme-tab-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `widget.name`. For example, if you are trying to access `assetImage` you can use `print('${widget.assetImage}');` Just a side note, this is to access the variables in your `StatefulWidget`. You can't do it for **any** class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited the post, the first was not the question i meant.

Answer (score 0):

you can get using widget

```
    widget.assetImage
    wiget.name
    print('${wiget.name}');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use in its create State class, you can access it via widget.assetImage Like

```
class _MyDragPlayerState extends State<MyDragPlayer> {
    ...
    // print('${widget.assetImage }');
    ...
}
```

but if you want to access in other classes than this you can declare variables as static like

```
class MyDragTarget extends StatefulWidget {
  static String assetImage;
  static String name;

  MyDragTarget(this.name, this.assetImage);

  @override
  _MyDragTargetState createState() => _MyDragTargetState();
}
```

and then in other class you can access via

```
class OtherClass{
    ...
    // print('${MyDragTarget.assetImage }');
    ...
}
```

check for null safety first, also read about pros and cons of using static variables.